# What is the theory behind this chord progression?

Tags: theory, chords, composition

first time posting here, although I've read quite a few posts before.

So, I was analyzing the theory behind a song (Savatage - Gutter Ballet), and while it is primarily in the key of D Minor, it starts with the following chord progression:

Bb - F - C - G

The only connection I could find was in fifths, being that F is the fifth of Bb, C is the fifth of F and G is the fifth of C. Well, I guess we could say each chord is a fourth above the previous one.
I've heard of secondary dominants, is there such a thing as secondary subdominants; and would it apply here? I'm honestly a bit stumped, especially since the rest of the song is fairly simple theory wise.

Cheers.

Comment: Very similar to 'Hey Joe', which takes the sequence a little further. Yet another one to argue about what key it's in...

Answer (score 2):

There could be a thing as secondary subdominants, but we can also explain this particular progression a bit more simply: we talk about V–I resolutions creating a large descending circle-of-fifths progression. G–C–F–B♭, for instance, is one such descending circle of fifths.

But here, we're going in the opposite direction: B♭–F–C–G! As such, this is just an *ascending* circle of fifths.

I don't know this song, but it's possible that this is part of a sequence, and that the music above the B♭ and F chords is all just moved up a step to happen over the C and G chords.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to explain it with anything fancy, the G major is the only small surprise there, bringing D Dorian taste, as opposed to, say, a Gm or Dm chord. If the chords were just Bb - F - C - Dm, I guess you wouldn't feel a need for any sort of analysis? I think the G major is the "money chord" there, bringing some recognizable character to the harmony.

To illustrate how I hear the chords, I made a folk style reduction of the chords. Does this bring out the character of the Bb - F - C - G sequence?

So, my analysis is that it's just something like IV - I - V - II in F major.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard gave a fulfilling answer;

Another approach you can take is that, after a listen to this intro, you can hear that they play Bb and C chords in the second inversion. So, there is a triad 'sliding' into third and fifth of F and G chords from the top. To me it feels more like a IV - I movement, so it sounds more like two [plagal cadences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence#Plagal_cadence), one after another.

Now, as it is not the end of a phrase and there is hardly a feeling of resolution, you can't call it a cadence in this case, so it is more about IV to I movement here: Bb(IV of F) to F, and C(IV of G) to G.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer already points out the possibility of a *harmonic sequence*. I just want to elaborate on that a bit.

As you pointed out roots by descending fifth are the well known *circle of fifths* progression. As a two chord gesture it starts like this...

[image]

...if you *sequence* that down a step, you get the beginning of the circle, but also notice that each iteration, each bar starts with a root position chord...

[image]

...one way you can think of the sequence of roots by descending fifths is simply a descending line of root position chords alternating with first inversion chords. The main point being to recognize the larger scale motion which is simply a descending line.

You can apply the same idea, but use an ascending line.

The starting unit could be a descending fifth...

[image]

...or a descending fourth...

[image]

...it doesn't matter. Either one can be used *sequentially* in either an ascending or descending line.

If we choose the descending fourth and then use it with an ascending line we get...

[image]

I highlighted the root position chords. In `D` minor you can see we get...

`Dm: III IV V`

...a very strong drive to the dominant in `D` minor which could very obviously continue in `D` minor.

I mention this point about the root position chords moving by step to try to demystify root progression by descending fifth of descending fourth. There are a lot of ways you can put together sequential harmony, but a lot of it can just be viewed as ascending or descending by step through important scale degrees. Also, a lot of pop music uses chord changes by step which looks like bad voice leading by classical standards. Being aware of the step-wise natural of harmonic sequences helps bridge the gap between the two styles.

OK, back to the song.

Take the six chords of this sequence, but elaborate progressions up to a structural level.

The intro uses the first four chords and repeats them. It begins the ascent, but the repetition delays the eventual goal of `D` minor. It builds anticipation, good for an intro.

After the intro we get to `D` minor. But rather than the straight forward `Dm` and `A` chords it's enlarged to a whole verse section using `Dm C Dm` and `F G`. It doesn't use the dominant. You could say the verse is a big elaboration of the tonic `Dm` chord.

When it gets to the chorus/refrain we finally get the dominant to tonic harmony. When he sings *gutter ballet* it uses chords `Bb A Dm` which on a large scale fulfills the sixth chord - the `A` major chord - of the basic harmonic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Its a string of IV-I resolutions.   Take it one further, to D, and you've Done The Time Warp. Again.  Not uncommon in today's music.

Comment: +1, because the intro sounds like it _could_ be a similar thing. But then the song starts and it's in Dm, and subsequent instances of the Bb - F - C - G sequence don't sound like a IV-I series anymore, so I can't completely agree.